# How to check NCQ functionality

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, barracuda

Normally you'd have to connect HDD directly to SATA controller inside PC to confirm NCQ functionality.

Is there a sure-fire way to check if RAID controller (EonStor FC with SATA) detects and works well with NCQ on Barracuda ES.2 SATA drives?  I use QLogic 24xx to connect.

Comment: This question is driven by the fact that SCSI over Fibre Channel hides SATA implementation details at the PC connected to RAID.  I am looking for a good hack around this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the RAID management software reports whether NCQ is being used I don't think you can be sure. However the documentation for the controller should tell you is NCQ is supported.

In any case, as long as you have write-back enabled the RAID controller should manage disk writes as well as NCQ if not better.

JR

Well http://www.nexstor.co.uk/products/3/46/126/660/Disk_Storage/Infortrend/FC_to_SATA/EonStor_FC-4G_to_SATA-II_2U_8-bay_12-bay_RAID_-_A08F_A12F-G2422 claims that NCQ is supported. Given how much you paid for it I think you should leave the worrying to the EonStor and sit back with a cup of coffee :-)

Comment: I am more concerned with disk reads, actually.  The RAID controller lists it as a feature, but doesn't explicitly show it in its management software.

Comment: Oh, and of course I use write-back cache :)

Comment: See my edit. I think you should trust the EonStor :-)

Comment: They do theirs, and I do mine.  We have a performance problem to solve in our software, so I'm chasing all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

1/2 OT: I was experiencing a performance gain of ca. 30% with random small I/O load when I was upgrading a pretty old EonStor A16F-... box to the newest firmware release.

Comment: I think A16F describes the enclosure.  I am using a G2430 controller.